# How do I read a local file in Deno?

Tags: typescript, deno

I'm writing a word count program written in TypeScript that I'm trying to run in Deno. I'm invoking it with no arguments, just `deno ./word_count.ts`, so it should have the default read-only filesystem access. I was hoping that I might be able to use [the standard browser `fetch()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) with [the `file:` URL scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) to read from the filesystem, like this:

**`word_count.ts`**

```js
const countWords = (s: string): number =>
s.split(/\s+/g).filter(w => /[a-z0-9]/.test(w)).length;

const main = async () => {
    const text = await (await fetch("file:///./input.txt")).text();
    const count = countWords(text);
    console.log(`I read ${count} words.`);
};

main();
```

**`input.txt`**

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

But when I try I see I see that `fetch` doesn't support `file` URLs:

```
Error: an error occurred trying to connect: invalid URL, scheme must be http
    at FetchResponse.onMsg (deno/js/fetch.ts:121:21)
    at FetchRequest.onMsg (deno/js/fetch.ts:152:19)
    at onFetchRes (deno/js/fetch.ts:28:8)
    at onMessage$1 (deno/js/main.ts:30:7)
```

---

How can I read the contents of a local file in Deno?

Comment: I opened an issue about `fetch()` syntax for files, track it @ https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/2150

Answer (score 33, accepted):

(**Update:** wrapping code in `async function main() { ... }` is no longer needed because Deno now supports [top-level `await`](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/471))

### Using built-in `Deno.readTextFile`

```
const countWords = (s: string): number =>
  s.split(/\s+/g).filter(w => /[a-z0-9]/.test(w)).length;

const text = await Deno.readTextFile('input.txt');
const count = countWords(text);
console.log(`I read ${count} words.`);
```

See the docs at: https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.readTextFile

### Using built-in `Deno.readFile`

```
const countWords = (s: string): number =>
  s.split(/\s+/g).filter(w => /[a-z0-9]/.test(w)).length;

const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

const text = decoder.decode(await Deno.readFile('input.txt'));
const count = countWords(text);
console.log(`I read ${count} words.`);
```

Note that you need to explicitly decode the data as UTF-8.

See the docs at: https://deno.land/typedoc/index.html#readfile

### Using blocking reads

The accepted answer uses `readFileSync()` which is a **blocking** function so the `main()` being `async` is not needed (**Update:** it is no longer needed for non-blocking `await` as well). A simplified (and working) example would be:

```
const countWords = (s: string): number =>
  s.split(/\s+/g).filter(w => /[a-z0-9]/.test(w)).length;

const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

const text = decoder.decode(Deno.readFileSync('input.txt'));
const count = countWords(text);
console.log(`I read ${count} words.`);
```

Note that there is no `await` anywhere, so the code is slightly simpler (**Update:** before Deno supported top-level `await` the difference in simplicity was bigger) but the `Deno.readFileSync()` will block the thread until the file is read - for a simple script that does a sequence of steps like in this example this is fine, but if it was inside a request handler in a server then it would be a disaster for the performance.

### Using lower-level `Deno.open` and `Deno.readAll`

```
const countWords = (s: string): number =>
  s.split(/\s+/g).filter(w => /[a-z0-9]/.test(w)).length;

const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

const file = await Deno.open('input.txt');
const text = decoder.decode(await Deno.readAll(file));
const count = countWords(text);
console.log(`I read ${count} words.`);
```

You could put the first two lines of `main()` in a single line:

```
const text = decoder.decode(await Deno.readAll(await Deno.open('input.txt')));
```

but it would be less readable.

See the docs at: https://deno.land/typedoc/index.html#readall

### Even lower-level `Deno.open` and `Deno.read`

You could use even lower-lever `Deno.read` but then you'd also have to allocate the buffers

See the docs at: https://deno.land/typedoc/index.html#read

### Using `new File()` abstraction

There is also a class-style abstraction for reading and writing files.

See the docs at: https://deno.land/typedoc/classes/deno.file.html

Comment: Hah, I was just listening to Ryan's latest talk last night and thinking "wait that's not the standard module structure I remember". Thanks for the updated answer.

Comment: This answer is now out of date with https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/tag/v1.2.1 `BREAKING(std/fs): remove readFileStr and writeFileStr` . Now Deno has `Deno.readTextFileSync` and `Deno.readTextFile` to use instead.

Answer (score 6):

> ⚠ **Obsolete:** This answer has been broken by the removal of the `'deno'` module in favour of the `Deno` global in [release v0.3.4](https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/tag/v0.3.4).

Deno includes a `readFileSync(filename: string): Uint8Array` function in its standard library, which is available at the special import path `'deno'`.

```js
import {readFileSync} from 'deno';

const bytes = readFileSync('./input.txt');
```

This reads the contents of the file as a byte array. If the file contains text that you want as a string, as in your example, you can use the standard ECMAScript `TextDecoder` class ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder)).

```js
const utf8Decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
const string = utf8Decoder.decode(bytes);
```

For the original example, this gives us:

**`word_count.ts`**

```js
import {readFileSync} from 'deno';

const countWords = (s: string): number =>
s.split(/\s+/g).filter(w => /[a-z0-9]/.test(w)).length;

const main = async () => {
    const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
    const bytes = readFileSync("./input.txt");
    const text = decoder.decode(bytes);
    const count = countWords(text);
    console.log(`I read ${count} words.`);
};

main();
```

Which produces the desired output:

```
$ deno ./word_count.ts
```

```
I read 9 words.
```

Answer (score 3):

#### std `0.62.0` / Deno `1.2.1` +

Since [`std v0.62.0`](https://github.com/denoland/deno/commit/25a0ad3e16e767d58b1315e9d12a236ea36c5998), `readFileStr` and `readFileStrSync` are [removed](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/6848) from Standard Library.

[`Deno.readTextFile`](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.readTextFile) and [`Deno.readTextFileSync`](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.readTextFileSync) have the same API and now are the way to go.

(same for `writeFileStr` / `writeFileStrSync`)